# Can't load contacts from iPhone to iCloud account

Tags: icloud, contacts, iphone

I have an iPhone 5S and I cannot seem to get my contacts loaded from my iPhone to my iCloud account.

I have reset the iCloud and also deleted the account on my phone and reset etc. but nothing has happened.

Answer (score 1):

On your iPhone be sure the following is set:

- Go to **Settings**
- Tap **iCloud**
- Set the slider beside **Contacts** to green [on]

  ---

  [image: iCloud settings iOS]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mac computer you can sync your contacts to your computer using iTunes, then export them, and then import them into iCloud. See http://discussions.apple.com/message/23278838#23278838.